# How to bind Ctrl+Tab to a function in python Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have tried many things like :

```
def change_tab_right(self, event):
        print(0)
        current_tab = self.notebook.tabs().index(self.notebook.get())
        print(current_tab)
        if current_tab == self.notebook.index("end"):
            self.notebook.select(self.notebook.tabs()[0])
        else:
            self.notebook.select(self.notebook.tab(current_tab + 1))

self.bind_all("<Control-Tab>", self.change_tab_right)
```

and all but nothing seem to work

I want to bind Ctrl+tab to a function but when I click Ctrl+Tab after dong the above one nothing happened. I even tried to test it with print statements but the that binding is just not calling the function.

Comment: I think the notebook widget overrides the control-tab binding. If you're trying to enable control-tab to traverse notebook tabs, you should try using the [enable_traversal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Notebook.enable_traversal) method of the notebook widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: `"<Control-Tab>"` merely used for indentaion.

Try this:

```
self.bind_all("<Shift-Tab>", self.change_tab_right)
```

Comment: Hmm that I could do

Answer (score 0):

try to bind Ctrl+Tab to your main window

```py
self.root.bind('<Control-Tab>', self.change_tab_right)
```

Comment: This is not working, and I dont have any element called self.root